# Lookalike shapes

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

### Similar figures

Two rectangles are *similar* if the ratios of their sides are the same.

Consider these two rectangles; a rectangle 5 lines tall and 11 chars wide:

```
===========
===========
===========
===========
===========
```

and a rectangle 10 lines tall and 22 chars wide:

```
======================
======================
======================
======================
======================
======================
======================
======================
======================
======================
```

These shapes are similar because the ratios of their sides are the same. To put it
formally (with \$h\$ being the shortest side and \$w\$ being the longest side):

$$
\frac{h_1}{w_1} = \frac{h_2}{w_2}
$$

You can also do:

$$
\frac{h_1}{h_2} = \frac{w_1}{w_2}
$$

### The challenge

Write a program or function that takes a "main" rectangle and some "other"
rectangles and prints which of "others" are similar to "main".

### The input

A shape and a list of shapes. Each shape consists of 2 non-zero positive integers, which denote the
width and height of the rectangle. For instance, this:

```
(4,2), (3,9)
```

denotes two rectangles, a 4x2 and a 3x9. The exact format of the input may be
however you desire.

### The output

The indices of the "other" shapes that are similar to "main". You may 
choose whether the indices are 0- or 1-based, as well as the exact format 
and order of the output.

### Sample program

In Python:

```
main = eval(raw_input()) # The main rectangle.
rects = eval(raw_input()) # The list of rectangles.
similar = set()
for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
    if max(main)*min(rect) == min(main)*max(rect): # Cross-multiply
        # They are similar.
        similar.add(i)

print similar
```

### Sample input and output

Input:

```
(1, 2)
[(1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

Output:

```
set([0, 1])
```

Input:

```
(1, 2)
[(1, 9), (2, 5), (16, 8)]
```

Output:

```
set([2])
```

### Winning

This is code-golf, so the shortest submission wins.

### Notes

- This should go without saying, but **standard loopholes are banned**.
- **No builtins for locating similar figures may be used.** (I don't even know if that exists, but I would't be surprised!)

Comment: Is using floating point division allowed? Would `[1.0 2.0]` be an acceptable input format?

Comment: @Dennis Provided your selected language doesn't have oddly low floating point precision and therefore the test cases fail, it should be fine. ;)

Comment: Instead of indices may we also output the actual similar shapes themselves?

Comment: @orlp Nope!!! :D

Comment: @Dennis The trouble with floating point is that you run into trouble in some cases. e.g., `[1.0 5.0]` is **not** the same as `[0.2 1.0]` because 0.2 is not representable in binary floating point. (That is, `5 * 0.2 != 1.0`.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I know, that's why I asked. `0.2` won't be an issue here though, since the input will always be an integer (in the mathematical sense).

Comment: What is (0,0) similar to? Also your sample program fails parsing `(3+i, 4-2i)`

Comment: @immibis You only need to handle non-zero integers, not imaginary numbers. I'll edit the post.

Comment: So they can be negative?

Comment: @immibis Uhh...nope. Editing...

Comment: Is the output format of outputting the indices mandatory? For a test case like  `[(1,2), (2,4), (1,9), (2,5), (16,8)]`, is only `[0,1,4]` and `[1,2,5]` allowed, or could we also output `[1,1,0,0,1]` or `[(1,2), (2,4), (16,8)]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
fqcFS@QTcFSvzUQ
```

Answer (score 11):

### Python, 61 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,l:[i for i,(x,y)in enumerate(l)if x/y in[a/b,b/a]]
```

Yes, I'm using spending 9 chars to write `enumerate`. Takes input like `1, 2, [(1, 9), (3,6), (2, 5), (16, 8)]`. For Python 2, input values need to be written as floats.

One char longer (62) in Python 3:

```python
def f(a,b,l,i=0):
 for x,y in l:b/a!=x/y!=a/b or print(i);i+=1
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining this? I'd like to know what's going on.

Comment: @BassetHound for each element in the input list, the comprehension unpacks`i` as the index, and `(x,y)` as the point. It then checks if the value `x/y` is either equal to the initial two numbers' quotient (`a/b`) or its reciprocal (`b/a`). If it is equal to one of those values, that value of `i` is added to the list, otherwise it is discarded.

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
{:$::/_0=f=ee::*0-}
```

The above is an anonymous function that pops a single array of floating point pairs (first pair is needle) from the stack and pushes the array of 1-based indexes in return.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B%3A%24%3A%3A%2F_0%3Df%3Dee%3A%3A*0-%7D~p&input=%5B%5B1.0%202.0%5D%20%5B1.0%209.0%5D%20%5B2.0%205.0%5D%20%5B16.0%208.0%5D%5D).

#### How it works

```
:$                e# Sort each pair.
  ::/             e# [a b] -> a/b
     _0=          e# Push a copy of the array and extract the first float (needle).
        f=        e# Check which floats are equal to the needle.
          ee      e# Enumerate the resulting Booleans.
            ::*   e# Multiply each Boolean by its index.
                  e# This yields 0 for the needle (index 0) and for non-matching
                  e# haystack pairs (Boolean 0).
               0- e# Remove all zeroes from the array.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
(a!b)l=[i|(i,(x,y))<-zip[0..]l,x/y+y/x==a/b+b/a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVBCsIwEAXQq/yCixk6NqZiqWBOErJIQHAwlqJdJOLdI32b94if5z3n1ih2ibPz@iMVKlKZb8evrv40DCFLMbWvpjgXTeqTiaG9oi5wWN@6bDiAOobFCE9WcGUBnWXaGwWXfTsJZg7tDw)

Call this like `(!) 1 2 [(1, 9), (3,6), (2, 5), (16, 8)]`.

A near-port of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/56040/20260). The expression `zip[0..]l` enumerates the list with its indices.

The expression `x/y+y/x==a/b+b/a` checks that the ratio `x/y` is either `a/b` or `b/a`, since the function `f(z) = z + 1/z` has `f(z) = f(1/z)` and no other collisions.

Comment: Maybe make `h` an operator taking three arguments? That'd save one byte, and I think it would stay within the rules.

Comment: @dfeuer Sure, it's definitely allowed by modern standards though back it was fuzzier what liberties could be taken with I/O.

Answer (score 7):

### [Snowman 1.0.2](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/releases/tag/v1.0.2-beta), 61 chars

```
}vgvgaC"[0-9]+"sM:10sB;aM2aG:AsO:nD;aF;aM0AAgaA*|:#eQ;AsItSsP
```

Pure gibberish (unless you happen to know Snowman), a.k.a. [exactly in line with the language's design goal](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/blob/57913d7894b744914d8ec660dcb70adfc5d3035b/doc/snowman.md) of being as confusing as possible.

Input format is same as in the post, output format is also the same minus `set(` and `)`.

Ungolfed (or unminified, really):

```
}vgvgaC     // read two lines of input, concatenate
"[0-9]+"sM  // use a regex to grab all numbers
:10sB;aM    // essentially map(parseInt)
2aG         // take groups of 2 (i.e. all the ordered pairs)

// now map over each ordered pair...
:
  AsO       // sort
  :nD;aF    // fold with division - with 2 array elements, this is just a[0]/a[1]
;aM

// we now have an array of short side to long side ratios
// take out the first one
0AAgaA      // active vars beg, b=array[0], g=the rest
*|          // store first ordered pair in permavar, bring the rest to top

// select indices where...
:
  #         // retrieve first ordered pair
  eQ        // equal?
;AsI

tSsP  // to-string and output
```

I'm pretty proud of some of the tricks I used in this one:

- I used the same input format as in the post. But instead of trying to parse it somehow, which would get really messy, I just concatenated the two lines and then used a regex to extract all the numbers into one big array (with which I then did `2aG`, i.e. get every group of 2).
- `:nD;aF` is pretty fancy. It simply takes an array of two elements and divides the first one by the second one. Which seems pretty simple, but doing it the intuitive way (`a[0]/a[1]`) would be far, far longer in Snowman: `` 0aa`NiN`aA|,nD `` (and that's assuming we don't have to worry about messing with other existing variables). Instead, I used the "fold" method with a predicate of "divide," which, for an array of two elements, achieves the same thing.
- `0AAgaA` looks innocuous enough, but what it actually does is store a `0` to the variables, then takes all variables with an index greater than that (so, all variables except for the first one). But the trick is, instead of `AaG` (which would get rid of the original array and the `0`), I used `AAg`, which keeps both. Now I use `aA`, at-index, using the *very same `0`* to get the first element of the array—furthermore, this is in consume-mode (`aA` instead of `aa`), so it gets rid of the `0` and original array too, which are now garbage for us.

  Alas, `0AAgaA*|` does essentially the same thing that GolfScript does in one character: `(`. However, I still think it's pretty nice, by Snowman standards. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
Position[a=Sort@#;Sort@#/a&/@#2,{x_,x_}]&
```

Usage:

```
Position[a = Sort@#; Sort@#/a & /@ #2, {x_, x_}] &[{1, 2}, {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {16, 8}}]
(* {{1}, {3}} *)
```

Comment: I just *knew* Mathematica was going to come up somehow!

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 14 bytes

Filters by comparing quotients, then maps `indexOf`.

```
xLQfqcFSTcFvzQ
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xLQfqcFSTcFvzQ&input=%281%2C+2%29%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%281%2C+2%29%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D%0A%281%2C+2%29%0A%5B%281%2C+9%29%2C+%282%2C+5%29%2C+%2816%2C+8%29%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

Comment: This doesn't sort the main shape, so it will give the wrong answer when the main shape's first side length is larger. See [this test case](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xLQfqcFSTcFvzQ&input=%282%2C+1%29%0A%5B%281%2C+9%29%2C+%282%2C+5%29%2C+%2816%2C+8%29%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Comment: @isaacg good point, will fix.

Comment: This fails on inputs with repeated elements, for example `1,2` and `[(1, 2), (2, 4), (1, 2)]` will give `[0, 1, 0]` rather than the correct `[0, 1, 2]`.

Comment: I want to accept this one, since it *is* the shortest, but is the problem @orlp mentioned fixed?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos [No.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xLQfqcFSTcFvzQ&input=%281%2C+2%29%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%281%2C+2%29%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%2C+%281%2C+2%29%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>16</s> 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
(=.×∘⌽∨=.×)⍤1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X8NW7/D0Rx0zHvXsfdSxAsTRfNS7xPB/2qO2CY96@x71TfX0f9TVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@b6hgpJCmYKpg9Kh3C4htpGCiYKhgCaRNFQzNFCwA)

-3 thanks to @ngn!

Explanation:

```apl
(=.×∘⌽∨=.×)⍤1
(     ∨   )   ⍝ "OR" together...
 =.    =.     ⍝ ...fold by equality of:
   ×∘⌽        ⍝ - the arguments multiplied by itself reversed
         x    ⍝ - the argument multiplied by itself
           ⍤1 ⍝ Applied at rank 1 (traverses)
```

Output format is a binary vector like `1 1 0 0 1` of which "other" rectangle is a look-a-like.

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
=/-×⍥(⌈/)¨⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/31Zf9/D0R71LNR71dOhrHlrxqGfv/7RHbRMe9fY96pvq6f@oq/nQeuNHbROBvOAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NQcNQwUhTQcNUwehR7xYgGwhNFAwVLIG0qYKhmYKFJgA)

Explanation:

```apl
=/-×⍥(⌈/)¨⌽ ⍝ takes only a right argument: ⍵, shape: (main (other...))
          ⌽ ⍝ two transformations:
  -         ⍝ - left (L) vectorized negation: -⍵
          ⌽ ⍝ - right (R): reverse. (main other) => (other main)
     (⌈/)¨  ⍝ transformation: calculate the max (since L is negated, it calculates the min)
            ⍝ (/ reduces over ⌈ max)
            ⍝ this vectorizes, so the "main" side (with only one rect) will get repeated once for each "other" rect on both sides
   ×⍥       ⍝ over multiplication: apply the transformation to both sides. F(L)×F(R)
=/          ⍝ reduce the 2-element matrix (the "main" that's now the side of the "other") to check which are equal
```

Output format is the same as the main Dyalog answer.

Thanks to Adám for the help golfing + Extended.

Comment: `(=.×∘⌽∨=.×)⍤1`

Comment: Thanks. Will try to inspect that first

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 62 bytes

```julia
f(m,o)=find([(t=sort(m).*sort(i,rev=true);t[1]==t[2])for i=o])
```

The `find` function locates true elements in a boolean vector. `.*` performs elementwise multiplication of vectors.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(m::Array, o::Array)
    find([(t = sort(m) .* sort(i, rev=true); t[1] == t[2]) for i in o])
end
```

Usage:

```julia
f([1,2], {[1,9], [2,5], [16,8]})
```

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 19 bytes

I think this will do the trick:

```
&(*t)=1_t:{%/x@>x}'
```

Takes a list of pairs where the first is the "main". Computes the ratio by dividing the sorted dimensions of each pair. Returns a list of the 0-indexed positions of the matching pairs. (arguably the input format I chose makes this -1 indexed- if this is considered invalid tack on a `1+` to the beginning and add two characters to the size of my program.)

Usage example:

```
  &(*t)=1_t:{%/x@>x}'(1 2;1 2;2 4;2 5;16 8)
0 1 3
```

This runs in [oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html)- note that I implicitly depend on division always producing floating point results. It would work in Kona if you added a decimal point to all the numbers in the input and added a space after the `_`.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave / Matlab, 44 bytes

Using an anonymous function:

```
@(x,y)find((max(x))*min(y')==min(x)*max(y'))
```

The result is in 1-based indexing.

To use it, define the function

```
>> @(x,y)find((max(x))*min(y')==min(x)*max(y'));
```

and call it with the following format

```
>> ans([1 2], [1 9; 2 5; 16 8])
ans =
     3
```

You can [try it online](http://ideone.com/cURDeg).

---

If the result can be in **logical indexing** (`0` indicates not similar, `1` indicates similar): **38 bytes**:

```
@(x,y)(max(x))*min(y')==min(x)*max(y')
```

Same example as above:

```
>> @(x,y)(max(x))*min(y')==min(x)*max(y')
ans = 
    @(x,y)(max(x))*min(y')==min(x)*max(y')

>> ans([1 2], [1 9; 2 5; 16 8])
ans =
 0     0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
z{iXhpᵐ/ᵛ∧Xt}ᵘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv6o6MyKjAMjSf7h19qOO5RElQOEZ//9HA4GhjlFsrA6E1ok20jGJBXORxC3B4qZA0tBMxwIoHQsA)

Takes input as a list *containing a list containing* the main rectangle and the list of other rectangles (so test case 1 is `[[[1,2]],[[1,2],[2,4]]]`), and outputs a list of 0-based indices through the output variable.

```
z                 Zip the elements of the input, pairing every "other" rectangle with the main rectangle.
 {          }ᵘ    Find (and output) every unique possible output from the following:
  iX              X is an element of the zip paired with its index in the zip.
    h             That element
      ᵐ           with both of its elements
     p            permuted
        ᵛ         produces the same output for both elements
       /          when the first element of each is divided by the second.
         ∧Xt      Output the index.
```

If that sort of odd and specific input formatting is cheating, it's a bit longer...

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
{hpX&tiYh;X/ᵛ∧Yt}ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wvzqjIEKtJDMywzpC/@HW2Y86lkeW1D7ctuD//@joaEMdo1gdGGWkYxIbi@ACKUuwqCmQNDTTsQBKxgIA)

Takes input as a list containing the main rectangle and the list of other rectangles (so test case 1 is the more obvious `[[1,2],[[1,2],[2,4]]]`), and outputs a list of 0-based indices through the output variable.

```
{               }ᵘ    Find (and output) every possible output from the following:
  p                   A permutation of
 h                    the first element of the input
   X                  is X,
    &                 and
      i               a pair [element, index] from
     t                the last element of the input
       Y              is Y,
        h             the first element of which
            ᵛ         produces the same output from
           /          division
         ;            as
          X           X.
             ∧Yt      Output the index.
```

To determine if two width-height pairs represent similar rectangles, it just takes the four bytes `pᵐ/ᵛ` (which outputs the shared ratio or its reciprocal). All the rest is handling the multiple rectangles to compare, and the output being indices.

Answer (score 2):

## [dzaima/APL](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 7 bytes

```apl
=/⍤÷⍥>¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsZ/W/1HvUsOb3/Uu9Tu0Ir/mv81HnU1GSoYaSqkKWiAaQ0jBRNNENsSzDYFsc0ULDT/5ReUZObnFf/XLQYA)

[8 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/R707bPUf9S45vP1R71K7Qyv@a/7XeNTVZKhgpKmQpqABpjWMFEw0QWxLMNsUxDZTsND8l19QkpmfV/xftxgA) outputting a list of indices instead of a boolean vector

```apl
      ¨ for each (pairing the left input with each of the right)
    ⍥>    do the below over sorting the arguments
=/          equals reduce
  ⍤         after
   ÷        vectorized division of the two
```

Comment: Although it's a nice answer, we have to output the indices. So your TIO test case should result in either `[0,1,4]` or `[1,2,5]` (not sure if your language is 0- or 1-indexed). It would have been a better challenge imho if all three output-formats are allowed: indices; filter to keep the truthy values; list of truthy/falsey values (like you have now), instead of only allowed indices.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen "You may choose [...] the exact format and order of the output." in APL it's _very_ common practice to store indices as a boolean vector, but you're right, that probably should be clarified.

Comment: Well, I read "_You may choose whether the indices are 0- or 1-based, as well as the exact format and order of the output._" as it can be `[0,1,4]`, `[1,2,5]`, `4\n0\n1`, `5 2 1`, etc. etc., since it still stated _indices_. But I've asked OP to clarify (if they response, since it's a 4 year old challenge). In my 05AB1E answer it would mean 14 bytes if the indices are mandatory vs 8 bytes if either of the other two options are allowed. Regardless, I upvoted your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 75 bytes

```
import Data.List
a(x,y)=max x y/min x y
s r=elemIndices(True).map((==a r).a)
```

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcUxCsMwDADAva9QIINclDTB0CzVS4wHDYWKRsa4GZzSv7vJcveSz/u5rq0JVtodm1SosN9M0/mldJmD/lDJ3GP4ag7TOMZMAsYsUGIz0cS5aNqgB/S0OOgg4Dz5q6fTxRHeyR/Oh7H9AQ)

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcQ7CsMwDADQvadQoINU1HwwNEt1EuNBQ6GicTBuBrvk7m7yhvfW7@e1LK0pFq4kUQuWoRLWodAld0m87Wgc6Xn/WfJj34fEClFEIYcW1VZJ2dYNroCOZ4IOPE6ju8187ojxwefTcWh/)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to mazzy x2</sup>

```powershell
param($x,$y,$b)$b|%{($i++)[$x/$y-($z=$_|sort)[0]/$z[1]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0OlQkelUkclSVMlqUa1WkMlU1tbM1qlQl@lUldDpcpWJb6mOL@oRDPaIFZfpSraMDa29n8tF5eaSpqCoYKRgoaGoY6Rpo6GkY4JkDTVsQSSIBFNLiUlJEVGOqYgCTMdC3QZgtpNsSsyAKn6DwA)

This slightly abuses the `input may be however you desire` clause by having the first shape's components come separately to save 3 bytes.

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$b|%{($i++)[$a[0]/$a[1]-($x=$_|sort)[0]/$x[1]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlUUclSVMlqUa1WkMlU1tbM1olMdogVh9IGsbqaqhU2KrE1xTnF5VogkUrgKKxtf9rubjUVNIUNAx1jDQVNMCUjoaRjgmQNNWxBJJmOsaamlxKSijKjHRMgVKGZjoWmHKYRoBEiFX2HwA)

Uses conditional indexing to swap between the current zero-based index and null based on whether or not the ratios line up. Luckily in this case, `$i` increments regardless of it being printed or not.

Comment: You can save more if you use `-` instead `-ne`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 57 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$x,$y=$_|sort
($i++)[$r-$y/$x]
if(!$r){$r=$y/$x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYxhS8MwEIa/51ec2U0SlqId61ChkP8hMuJ6nYGydUnEjra/va6Zrvsk3pe7e3iftz58kfMfVFUDlnk7oHE7381bbBSectx0/uACE2gXC/mKLsHTAzZvzJbiDp1s0eWR9P3QMzYDuy/sljwYR5Am78ZTwbRgcB4ltEjVUq2kgnhNW4uItcjU8@VLpbxKY3CcSVqqbIyla/V0k/tn@QgnaXVTnv0hPUZLQgdzaKON1NS0DVQoQAM54OaCHfnPKpzBPZagDczA15UJwe53McBR8J8QT@jIrz1cvvzanPVs@AY)

Indices are 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 75

```
(a,b)=>b.filter(e=>e.l*a.h==a.l*e.h||e.l*a.l==a.h*e.h).map(e=>b.indexOf(e))
```

Alternative, also 75

```
(a,b)=>b.map((e,i)=>e.l*a.h==a.l*e.h||e.l*a.l==a.h*e.h?i:-1).filter(e=>e+1)
```

Input is taken as a JSON object, and an array of JSON objects

```
{
    l: length of rectangle,
    h: height of rectangle
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works with the second test case.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos sorry didn't see that part. It's fixed (but I'm sure I can golf it more)

Comment: These are not JSON objects, these are plain javascript objects. JSON is a data transfer format.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ʒ‚ε{ü/}Ë}J¹Jsk
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KRHDbPOba0@vEe/9nB3rdehnV7F2f//R0cb6hjF6kQb6ZjExnKBOQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmWCvpJCYl6KgZA9kPGqbBGRUJoS6hP0/NSniUcOsc1urD@/Rrz3cXesV6VWc/V/nfzQQGOoYxepEG@mYxMbqKIB5QFoBLGEJljAFkoZmOhYI@VgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ʒ               # Filter the (implicit) input-list by:
 ‚              #  Pair the current width/height with the (implicit) input width/height
  ε             #  Map both width/height pairs to:
   {            #   Sort from lowest to highest
    ü/          #   Pair-wise divide them from each other
      }Ë        #  After the map: check if both values in the mapped list are equals
        }J      # After the filter: join all remaining pairs together to a string
          ¹J    # Also join all pairs of the first input together to a string
            s   # Swap to get the filtered result again
             k  # And get it's indices in the complete input-list
                # (which is output implicitly)
```

The `J`oins are there because 05AB1E can't determine the indices on multidimensional lists a.f.a.i.k.

---

If outputting the width/height pairs that are truthy, or outputting a list of truthy/falsey values based on the input-list, it could be **8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead:

```python
ʒ‚ε{ü/}Ë
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KRHDbPOba0@vEe/9nD3///R0YY6lrE60UY6pkDS0EzHIjaWCyhmFAsA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmWCvpJCYl6KgZA9kPGqbBGRUJoS6hP0/NSniUcOsc1urD@/Rrz3c/b9W5380EBjqGMXqRBvpmMTG6iiAeUBaASxhCZYwBZKGZjoWCPlYAA).

```python
ε‚ε{ü/}Ë
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NZHDbPOba0@vEe/9nD3///R0YY6lrE60UY6pkDS0EzHIjaWCyhmFAsA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmWCvpJCYl6KgZA9kPGqbBGRUJoS6hP0/tzXiUcOsc1urD@/Rrz3c/b9W5380EBjqGMXqRBvpmMTG6iiAeUBaASxhCZYwBZKGZjoWCPlYAA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 10 bytes

```
⊚↥∩/=⊃×÷⊙⍉
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqa4oi6KOKGpeKIqS894oqDJ8OX4oeMw5cpCmYg4oaQIOKKmuKIuigvPcOX4oa74omF4oip4o2PLCwpCmYg4oaQIOKKmuKGpeKIqS894oqDJ8OX4oeMw5fiipnijYkKZiDihpAg4oqa4oi6KOKGpeKIqS894oqDw5fDtykKZiDihpAg4oqa4oal4oipLz3iioPDl8O34oqZ4o2JCmYgMV8yIFsxXzIgMl80IDNfNSAxNl84XQpmIDNfNSBbMV8yIDE1XzkgM181IDE2Xzhd)

-2 if I can take the second input transposed.

```
⊚↥∩/=⊃×÷⊙⍉    input: a shape S, a list of shapes M (2d matrix with two columns)
          ⊙⍉    transpose the 2nd input
      ⊃×÷        fork(mul, div): take S and M and give S*M and S/M
                  the operations are done between each item of S and each row of M
   ∩/=            both(reduce by equal): for each of the two matrices,
                  compare the two rows elementwise and give 1 when equal
                  for similar shapes, * gives 1 if in reverse order, / otherwise
  ↥               boolean OR of the two vectors
⊚                vector of indices of ones
```